# How to redirect the incoming traffic to a module to its simple submodule in Omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I have this code where a module which extends WirelessHost module is composed of a simple module called node :
When I run the simulation, there's only mobility events, no communication events are displayed. I think this is due to not
linking Drone gates module with gates that receive incoming traffic. How can I do this please?

---

```
                            SaaS.ned
```

---

```
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.physicallayer.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;

simple Node
{
    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}

module Drone extends WirelessHost
{                 
        gates:
            input in[];
            output out[];

         submodules:
            myNode: Node;

        connections allowunconnected:    
            for i=0..sizeof(in)-1 {
                in++ -->  myNode.in++;
            }
            for i=0..sizeof(out)-1 {
                out++ <--  myNode.out++;
            }
}

network SaaS
{
    parameters:
        int numDrones;

    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            @display("p=94.376,433.728");
        }

        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.0.0'/></config>");
                @display("p=94.376,56.224;is=s");
        }

        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium {
            @display("p=94.376,178.71199");
        }

        drone[numDrones]: Drone {
            @display("i=misc/node_vs");
        }
}
```

---

```
                           Node.cc
```

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class Node : public cSimpleModule
{
     protected:
      // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
      virtual void initialize() override;
      virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Node);
using namespace std;

void Node::initialize()
{
    int n = gateSize("out");
    cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMessage");
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
            send(msg, "out", i);
}

void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    int n = gateSize("out");
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        send(msg, "out", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not, how a `WirelessHost` in INET is supposed to be configured.

You should implement an UDP application module and you must configure that application to be used in the `WirelessHost`.

```
*.drone[0].numApps = 1
*.drone[0].app[0].typename = "MyUDPApp"
```

There is no need to extend the `WirelessHost` as it already contains a module vector called `app` which can be configured with the various application modules. You should check the various examples how applications are configured in them.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in the context of my project i should not use udp application. Each mobile wireless node should discover its neighbors and send a different packet to each of them without using any routing protocol or udp application.

Comment: I understand that you don't need a routing protocol because you just want to communicate with the neighboring nodes. However I don't see where the 'should not use an UDP application' requirement is coming from? In the SaaS network you have included an IPv4Configurator, so you clearly want to use the IP network layer and you want to use IPv4 addresses to address the nodes. UDP is nothing else just a multiplexer over the IP layer that adds ports to the address allowing to run multiple applications on a single node. Using UDP has nothing to do with the fact that you don't want a routing protocol.

Comment: So the most logical way to do it, is to extend the UdpBasicApp, and use it to communicate between WirelessHosts?

Comment: Yes, but note that in an INET 4 application you can also open sockets directly to lower levels in the OSI stack not just directly to transport layer (i.e. TCP or UDP). You can also open a socket to the link layer (Radio module) and pass that directly to/from it. In that case you could skip the network and transport layer, but of course you should use hardware addresses instead of IP in that case. I highly recommend reading the socket programming chapter in the INET dev guide: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-sockets.html

UDPSocket or IPv4Socket might be interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will try extending the UdpApp, and then see with sockets.